# Combine Grep and Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, input, while-loop, stdout

Have a list of smaller network elements that i am trying to list in the stdout.
My small little script works up until the regex, after i get prompted what i want to search for it lists the whole line.

Example:

Please Enter a Region

**Input**: Bei

**Output**:

ipc-bei640-r-br-01

ipc-bei640-r-br-02

ipc-bei640-r-br-03

Instead of :

bei640-01

bei640-02

bei640-03

Also if i just hit "Enter" in the input it lists all devices.

```
lines = IO.readlines("/usr/local/bin/braslist.txt")

devices = []
str = File.read('braslist.txt')

while true
print "Please enter a region. If you want to exit enter exit "
input = gets.chomp
exit if input == 'exit'

#Opens file and greps for input
File.open("braslist.txt", "r+") do |f|
    f.each do |line|
     devices += line.split(" ").grep(/#{input}/i)
     input.scan(/^ipc-(?<bng>[a-z]{3}\d{3})-r-br(?<nr>-\d{2})$/).map(&:join)
        end
end


puts devices
puts "#{devices.length} network elements found"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looping over the result of the grep like so:

```
File.open("braslist.txt", "r+") do |f|
   f.each do |line|
     line.split(" ").grep(/#{input}/i).each do |string|
       match = string.match(/^ipc-(?<bng>[a-z]{3}\d{3})-r-br(?<nr>-\d{2})$/)
       devices << match[:bng] + match[:nr]
     end
   end
end
```

(I also think using match instead of scan makes things a bit clearer)

Comment: Works like a charm, just what i was looking for.